# why Doesn't see List type?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using declare an array -

```
  final List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> listDropDown;
```

And I use the following construction -

```
class DropDown extends StatelessWidget {

  final String dropDownValue;
  final List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> listDropDown;

  DropDown(this.dropDownValue, this.listDropDown);
```

But I get an error -

```
The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>?'.
```

In this place -

```
return DropdownMenuItem(
                      value: dropDownValue,
                      child: Text(items, style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Mark-Pro", fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: configColors.darkBlue),),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
```

full dropDownButtom -

```
child: DropdownButton(
                  items: listDropDown.map((String items) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem(
                      value: dropDownValue,
                      child: Text(items, style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Mark-Pro", fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: configColors.darkBlue),),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                  // Initial Value
                  value: dropDownValue,

                  // Down Arrow Icon
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),

                  // Array list of items

                  // After selecting the desired option,it will
                  // change button value to selected value
                  onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                    mystate(() {
                      dropDownValue = newValue!;
                    });
                  },
                ),
```

Comment: Can you include full dropdownButton

Comment: Well, at least give us the whole code block, it's impossible to suggest a fix if we don't know the full statement that ends in `.toList()`.

Comment: I've added the code, I hope it's clear now

Comment: you need to check the code where you have created DropDown() and pass the list as a parameter that is incorrect type.  so you have not added that code in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in calling DropDown, you are passing List instead of List<DropdownMenuItem> to DropDown's listDropDown.

try this:

```
DropdownButton<String>(
                  items: listDropDown.map((String items) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      value: dropDownValue,
                      child: Text(items, style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Mark-Pro", fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: configColors.darkBlue),),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                  // Initial Value
                  value: dropDownValue,

                  
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                  onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                    mystate(() {
                      dropDownValue = newValue!;
                    });
                  },
                )
```

Comment: please add the part you are using DropDown widget

Comment: I've added the code, I hope it's clear now

Comment: I updated my answer, hope its help you.

Answer (score 1):

Once you like to use map on `final List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> listDropDown;`
it will be  `items: listDropDown.map((DropdownMenuItem items) {`.

As for your use case, you don't need to pass  `List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>` , just pass `List<String>`

```dart
class DropDown extends StatelessWidget {
  final String dropDownValue;
  final List<String> listDropDown;

  const DropDown(this.dropDownValue, this.listDropDown);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        DropdownButton<String>(
          items: listDropDown.map((String items) {
            return DropdownMenuItem(
              value: dropDownValue,
              child: Text(
                items,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: "Mark-Pro",
                    fontSize: 18,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    color: configColors.darkBlue),
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
          // Initial Value
          value: dropDownValue,
```